# Present context menu on MKAnnotationView

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mkannotationview, mkmapviewdelegate

I want to be able to present a context menu when tapping on a `MKAnnotationView` directly, in addition to the callout accessory view.

So for example,

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
     let FirstAction = UIAction(title: "First Action"),
                                   handler: {_ in
          print("First action")
      })
                
      let secondAction = UIAction(title: "Second Action",
                                  handler: {_ in
          print("Second action")
      })
                
      let button = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
      button.menu = UIMenu(title: "My Title"                               
                           children: [firstAction, secondAction])
      button.showsMenuAsPrimaryAction = true
      view.canShowCallout = true
      view.rightCalloutAccessoryView = button
}
```

Then in `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` I would like to perform the same action as tapping on the `rightCalloutAccessoryView (UIButton)` which shows the context menu `(UIMenu)`.  I thought maybe this would do the trick

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    control.sendActions(for: .primaryActionTriggered)
}
```

but that does not work.  Perhaps I am passing the wrong `Event` to `sendActions()`?  Or maybe it's just not possible?  At any rate, any assistance is much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

you can use `changesSelectionAsPrimaryAction` api available from iOS 15 to display menu as primary action for button selection, add for your button

```
button.changesSelectionAsPrimaryAction = true
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but that alone did not work.  Do I need to make other coding changes above, particularly in `func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl)`?